# Display certain contents of a website into webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

im try to load dynamic certain contents of a website into webview but i cant 
i use this code `public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// blog url
static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.internationalnewscenter.com/";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set layout view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // process
    try {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(getBlogStats());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Error");
    }
}

protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    // get html document structure
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
    // selector query
    Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#lofslidecontent45");
    // check results
    if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
        // get value
        result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
    }

    // return
    return result;
}
```

}
but it display for me an " error "`
is any one can help me or give me a link for full example to do that

Comment: add ex.printstacktrace(); and tell me what's showing up the console

Comment: where i should add this

Comment: } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printstacktrace();
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Error");
    }

Comment: anyway I recomend you to use a webservice instead

Comment: [2013-10-01 13:45:35 - international] Installing international.apk...
[2013-10-01 13:45:52 - international] Success!
[2013-10-01 13:45:52 - international] Starting activity com.example.international.MainActivity on device YT9100KHZ4
[2013-10-01 13:45:54 - international] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.international/.MainActivity }

Comment: do youy have an example do this task using webservice ??? please help me

Comment: add just the exception is in orange but probably you hyave got the exception bellow that takaki point out, follow the suggestion to pass through

Comment: you need to buid an script in the server side, I don't know if it's possible in your case, otherwise you are parsing a website that it may change and your app stops working

Answer (score 1):

It will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException if you call *Jsoup.connect* on the main thread.

Try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to connect to the blog, retrieve the content, and then set it to display in the TextView.

See the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) for a good example of this.

Also, don't forget to add the INTERNET permission to your manifest!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```